# python concatenate static text with variable

Tags: python

I am having an issue trying to concatenate static text with a variable. The variable prints without an issue but when I try to add the static text to it I dont get any output. Here is what I have so far, any thoughts how this can be fixed?

```
for tweet in status:
    singletweet = 'URL' + tweet.GetId()
    print singletweet
```

Comment: What do you want to get? What are you getting? What have you tried?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with this piece of code. Your princess is in another castle.

Comment: If `tweet.GetId()` is returning a string, that would work just fine. Chances are it is not returning a string. You could try doing `'URL' + str(tweet.GetID())`. To check the type being returned, you could use `type tweet.GetID()`

Comment: I am getting no result and no error. What I would like to get is URL1234 or the static phrase 'URL' plus the value of tweet.Get(Id). I tried print tweet.GetId() and it works perfectly (without the URL in the front).

Comment: Do `print status` before `for tweet in status` and give us output.

Comment: nothing at all?  what's `print list(status)`?

Comment: Thank you xbonez - that worked!! I had to convert to string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does `print type(tweet.GetId())` say? I'm not sure why you're not getting a traceback - perhaps a higher level is catching it and throwing it away.

If it's not a string, you'll have to convert it to one

```
singletweet = 'URL' + str(tweet.GetId())
```

or

```
singletweet = 'URL%s'%tweet.GetId()  # For Python2.5 or older
```

or

```
singletweet = 'URL{id}'.format(id=tweet.GetId())  # For Python2.6 or newer
```

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the second part of the concatenation to a string:

```
singleTweet = 'URL' + str(tweet.GetID())
```